# Fullscreen view for a collectionview

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

This is more of an approach question. Suppose I have a collection view where each cell is occupying the entire screen, which have images in them and some other data(eg: title, info etc). What I want is for the user to tap on the cell and the image to go to fullscreen mode. I am able to achieve this by initializing a separate view and scaling the image to fit the screen with this code.

```
            let newImageView = UIImageView(image: imageView.image)
            newImageView.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
            newImageView.backgroundColor = .black
            newImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

and then dismissing it by removing the view like so:

```
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
        navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false
        sender.view?.removeFromSuperview()
    }
```

Q1. Is there a way I can manipulate all the collectionview cells to transform into the fullscreen view on tap so i can use the default swiping action of the collection view to scroll through the images horizontally ?

Q2. If not, I use this library [INSPhotoGallery](https://github.com/inspace-io/INSPhotoGallery)! to add the effect on tap, which gives me the desired effect but due to heavy loading of the images from the PHAsset library my app crashes.

This is how i initialized my phassets to pass into this library:

```
lazy var photos: [INSPhotoViewable] = {
        var allPhotos: [INSPhoto] = Array()
        fetchResult.enumerateObjects({ (asset, index, stop) in
            let image = self.requestImageForPHAsset(asset: asset)
            allPhotos.append(INSPhoto(image: image, thumbnailImage: nil))
        })

        return allPhotos
    }()

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // handle tap events
        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! DetailedCollectionViewCell
        let currentPhoto = photos[indexPath.row]
        let galleryPreview = INSPhotosViewController(photos: photos, initialPhoto: currentPhoto, referenceView: cell)

        galleryPreview.overlayView.photosViewController?.singleTapGestureRecognizer.isEnabled = false

        galleryPreview.referenceViewForPhotoWhenDismissingHandler = { [weak self] photo in
            if let index = self?.photos.index(where: {$0 === photo}) {
                let indexPath = IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)
                return collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? DetailedCollectionViewCell
            }
            return nil
        }
        present(galleryPreview, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Question being how can I prevent my app from crashing. I know this has something to do with caching the images and loading asynchronously. Do you know of a library that integrates well with PHAssets if nothing else? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. You also can use page view controller to achieve the same functionality. It's valuable if you have less then 5 cells.
2. You can display image in a full screen modally. Just create separate view controller and implement animators(transition delegates) for this modal screen. It will be more difficult but also more proper way. The AppStore working in the same way